# What regular expression should I use to replace dimension constants

Tags: regex, eclipse, search, replace

```
ID_FLOWER_128X128_JPG
ID_APPLE_100X100_ICO
ID_ORANGE_64X64_PNG
ID_SUN_DIAL_64X64_PNG
ID_COMPUTER_16X16_ICO
```

I have several constants which have been declared like this, what regular expression should I use to replace the dimensions of those constants (e.g. 16X16 or 128X128) to an empty string, so it should look like the following post replacement

```
ID_FLOWER_JPG
ID_APPLE_ICO
ID_ORANGE_PNG
ID_SUN_DIAL_PNG
ID_COMPUTER_ICO
```

Note: All such strings with the ID_ prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find (assuming everything is in uppercase):

```
(ID_.+_)\d+X\d+_(.+)
```

The key bit in that regex is `\d+X\d+` which looks for at least 1 numeric digit, followed by X, followed by at least 1 numeric digit.

Replace with:

```
$1$2
```

Comment: The above expression doesn't translate properly, post translation it comes out as ID_COMPUTER_16ICO

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

`(.*)_[0-9]*[Xx][0-9]*_(.*)`

Replace with:
`$1_$2`

To test regexp in Eclipse use [Eclipse Regular Expression (RegExp) Tester](http://myregexp.com/eclipsePlugin.html) is a very nice plugin.